# SVN or SCP creating .tmp files

Tags: svn, scp

So we have two automated processes on our build system.  The first performs an svn export which exports a project to directory A.  The second performs an scp which scps a project from directory A to a different machine.  Sometimes, possibly due to a race condition, a situation arises in which a whole bunch of .tmp files are created, almost as if one of the transfers is stuck in a loop.

My question is simple, do either of these processes create .tmp files in their execution?  I'm trying to figure out which step is misbehaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer.  This can occur in svn when exporting symbolic links.  If the directory you are exporting to exists you have to use the --force command.  However, if that directory A contains a directory A/B and you have a symbolic link in A named B it will fail to export and it will leave a file named B.tmp behind.  If B.tmp exists it will create B.1.tmp and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Subversion definitely does. There's subversion-commit.tmp for failed commits, there are probably others created during normal operation.